# Why is the getTotals() method not working?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm creating a finance app that, with each item that is inserted, the "income", "expenses" and "balance" tables at the top are updated according to the values ​​entered by the user. For example, if the code receive a income value from the user, the "Receitas" and "Saldo" boxes have to be updated and receive these values. As it is, the code is not working. What should I do?

```js
normalizeNumbers(value) {
        const newValue = value.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "BRL"
        });
        return newValue;
    }
    getTotals() {
        const newReceitas = this.valores.filter(({ checked }) => {
            checked === '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-up arrowUp-icon"></i>';
        }).map(({ valor }) => +valor);
        console.log(newReceitas);
        const newDespesas = this.valores.filter(({ checked }) => {
            checked == '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-arrow-down arrowDown-icon"></i>';
        }).map(({ valor }) => +valor);
        console.log(newDespesas);
        const totalReceitas = newReceitas.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            return acc + curr;
        }, 0);
        const totalDespesas = newDespesas.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            return acc + curr;
        }, 0);
        const totalSaldo = +totalReceitas - +totalDespesas;
        this.receitas.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(+totalReceitas);
        this.despesas.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(+totalDespesas);
        this.saldo.innerText = this.normalizeNumbers(totalSaldo);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGCev.png)

Comment: Explain how it is not working please.  The totals shown in your screenshot seem to be formatted correctly.

Comment: If the user inserts a income value, the value is shown at the income box, if he inserts a expense value, the value is shown at the expense box but as it is, the boxes values keeps "R$ 0,00".

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code above, since I don't know the values of the `valores` array, I presume it's because of the filter callbacks, which never return a value and return empty arrays.

Either add `return`

```
({ checked }) => {
  return checked == '....'
}
```

or use arrow function

```
({ checked }) => checked == '....'
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwgByQQxgXhgcgDwCWMwANmhBJgEQBmaAtBABZoBOyMdjIJBcnDNqxAB3enFFgYQ0QBFJ9AqDBUAfHgD0BVTgCwAKGXQYrBMAQEoGbPiKlylWg2ZsOXCDz4D6MsQFcOXwBVZEVlNU1tHABuAwMoAE9UGAA1NBIQViwYAG8DGALiJjMAawQ4AC4YaFYCMABzfMKAN3TMqrA-AFsAIwRWAwBfOMMyChgAQVyRwpMzCysIbJw9fSaCxBR0JZtV9er0iWW9tf1ZoyhWP2AoTIAKZD8e3mAYVozTCCq0j4BtAF1sgCAJS5GDDU6zMCZLrpAgALwQADlun1WBA7u8-AgOqj+qC8mdZoULjAwAgRD9sdksQgAHS3AAyIGA6QQAGVLnV6ncqMgoPQAEIAJSoABppkTicToAkSDiYFRgH5WKYwMAEuL9tKCsrVQh1QkqlQRYyqNrCoNgbEpcTTFAVVJyZT0tibbMIft6ggoAAVEBWEgYgkW3XgYzO4XzSzkbJQJgECB096ZJB0mgEEhQfp3O45Iqlcrg4FVHogHgINBSTCqSU6u0+x0F4BlfiYdtzcwx0PFumw5C5-MprJWrC1gDUw+tMx1RgrdIyPMj0cW08hs-DsGdsiQqAgsew8cTyban3TmezrEHzdbxdL5flVbHdfrhXtTeAxRbRY7mz3aB7K0+zQAc8zeU9i2fSdTzXHs53lBcQCXCkdy2fcIFg21zk3GBbkDKMu0WbJl0I8g6VMOBrgQXM0GAYAJT1VhQRrF9XzmB1WCkWjXnHYgVVYd0dUGCUAAZMPrUk8PSVD-x2MkUN3bZyPKKiaLohj+OY2tCTYgp3046Q6JgXjGME6VhJgMSbTgnCpJIdlDhAbJxzsgiFljehjLsmTtjM4kjyTUxSLkgK6WhVhYV4REUV6foMRcgN0jcmMML82ZQr-bY4wTJNwsihFkTxdE7gSwMfPQtd61C-cSCOQ8crCmE4WioqMTshzapASrLSGEYDFJHpiIpSY7l+HSSS-VsqlsYgxkcdwWHYbwPF4fguF8cRJGkVU5AUJRwAiLQdDFfZhyqABGABmIYJXG3VJvKabCFmhxqAW1xls8NbBB2-xAl+kIwgO9QjpwE7bTOmBzoAdiGf5gQMHo6W9P1EqDO4EcMcN50XO4emBIA)